# I have written a code for character count. Is there a way to optimize this C++ code (in terms of time, space complexity etc.)?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector

```
//Code for Character Count
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector <char> s_character;
std::vector <int>  count_occurence;


/*Function to check occurence of a character in the character vector,
if found return position,
else return -1 indicating no occurence
*/

int check_character_occurence(char character)
{
    for (int i=0;i<s_character.size();i++)
    {
        if(s_character.at(i)==character)
            return i;
    }    

    return -1;

}//end_of_check_character_occurence_function


/*Function to do the counting of individual characters,
if character is not present(occuring for the first time) then add to both character vector and count vector
else update count at position
*/

void count_algorithm(char character)
{
    int pos_flag;

    pos_flag = check_character_occurence(character);

    if (pos_flag==-1)
    {
        s_character.push_back(character);
        count_occurence.push_back(1);
    }

    else
        count_occurence.at(pos_flag)++;

}//end_of_count_algorithm_function


int main() 
{
    std::string  sequence;
    char separated_character;

    std::cout<<"\nEnter String: ";
    std::cin>>sequence;
    std::cout<<"\nLength is "<<sequence.length()<<" characters.";

    for(int i=0; i<sequence.length(); i++)
    {
        separated_character=sequence[i];
        count_algorithm(separated_character);
    } 

    for(int i=0;i < s_character.size(); i++)
        std::cout<<"\nCharacter: "<<s_character[i]<<" Occurence: "<<count_occurence[i];

    return 0;

}//end_of_main_code
```

For testing I took a DNA sequence sample.

Output:

Enter String: AGCTAGCATCGTGTCGCCCGTCTAGCATACGCATGATCGACTGTCAGCTAGTCAGACTAGTCGATCGATGTG

Length is 72 characters.

Character: A Occurence: 16

Character: G Occurence: 19

Character: C Occurence: 19

Character: T Occurence: 18

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: I mean if it can be executed faster.

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are different languages - use only the relevant tag.

Comment: If this is working code and you want improvement suggestions then [codereview.se] is a more appropriate forum for this.

Comment: @kaylum Sorry for the tags mess, I picked 'C' from suggestion and thank you for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are storing both encountered chars and counters in vectors dynamically resizing them and performing search by iterating over all elements every time. The total number of characters is know (assuming 256). So you could declare counters as array and index them by char.

```
std::array< int, 256 > counters{};
for(int i=0; i<sequence.length(); ++i)
{
    ++counters[sequence[i]];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't fixing a size to 256 characters increase space complexity? I mean if distinct characters are less and have less occurrences.

Comment: No, since we will need to eventually allocate the same 256 characters for vector anyway (given input string varies enough). Actually having array reduces space complexity because we don't need vectors anymore.

Comment: @PlabanBiswas & VTT the asymptotic space complexity doesn't change either way. It remains constant. (time complexity doesn't change either, it remains linear)

Comment: @user2079303 As per my understanding time complexity is O(n^2), is there any other way to reduce it?

Comment: @PlabanBiswas whoops, I overlooked your `check_character_occurence`. Indeed, the approach in this answer does then improve the time complexity to linear. Not because the vector isn't resized, but because you no longer do a linear search for position.

Comment: @user2079303 VTT Thanks, I got the idea. Just one more question, since solution suggested by  VTT is having a fixed boundary, any other method with dynamic implementation?